# Can I convert an Appointment on my MS Outlook Calendar to a Lync Meeting?

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2013, lync-2013

Can I convert an Appointment on my MS Outlook Calendar to a Lync Meeting?

I have over twenty people attending several meetings that now need to be Lync meetings. Do I have to delete the Appointments and create new Lync Meetings and retype each name in order to invite them?

Answer (score 0):

The answer is: Yes!

Just open the meeting in Outlook Calendar, click the Lync Meeting button and send update to all invited.

Done!